# Highlight a q-table row (change the row color) when the rowclick event is triggered

Tags: quasar

How to highlight a q-table row (change the row color) when the rowclick event is triggered?

```
 <q-table>
    ...
    @row-click="onRowClickChangeRowColor"
 </q-table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use @click on the body slot. Please `refer` to the following codepen it will help you.

codepen - https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/jOWLbaR